# How to reload collectionview while still keeping order when adding new data

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I implemented Pagination into my project and noticed when inserting new data and reloading the collectionview I would go from Item 52 to Item 34. Is there anyway to stay at Item 52 and going on instead of going back to Item 34? Any help would be appreciated

[Gif of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaQgy.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try the following solution with different way

1. you can reload the collection for last visible index

   `yourCollectionView.reloadItems(at: collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)`
2. call the below method when **add new item** || **on cell selection** || **from any other method** from where you want to update the collection items get the index path which you want to view and pass into method

   ```
    func reloadCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,index:IndexPath){

    let contentOffset = collectionView.contentOffset
    collectionView.reloadData()
    collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    collectionView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false) 
    }
   ```

**e.g** in collection did select item i'm calling this method with following way

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      self.reloadCollectionView(collectionView: self.yourCollectionView, index: indexPath)

}
```

Hope this solution may helps you

Comment: Although this solves the problem of retaining the position, when scrolling back to the start, Cells in the Collectionview began to overlap. Is there any fix for this?